# Hover is still active after action on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: Anyone please?

I got this from somewhere but when I tap on it on the phone (on PC it's ok) it stays with hover attributes = no BG and black colour to the next website refresh:

HTML

```
<a id="back2Top" title="Top" href="#">&#10148;</a>
```

CSS

```
#back2Top {
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 39px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #8db500;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#back2Top:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
#back2Top {
    bottom: 0px;
}}
```

And JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (height > 100) {
        $('#back2Top').fadeIn();
        $('.open').css('background', 'rgba(141, 181, 0, 0.5)'); //these 3 are for something different
        $('.closed').css('background', 'rgba(201, 0, 10, 0.5)');
        $('.warn').css('background', 'rgba(255, 113, 0, 0.5)');

    } else {
        $('#back2Top').fadeOut();
        $('.open').css('background', 'rgba(141, 181, 0, 1)'); //these 3 are for something different
        $('.closed').css('background', 'rgba(201, 0, 10, 1)');
        $('.warn').css('background', 'rgba(255, 113, 0, 1)');
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#back2Top").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        return false;
    });

});
```

What is wrong there? Or what I did wrong?
×I don't know what to add more here, it won't let me post it because of mostly code.×
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right then you're trying to make an icon to go to the Top.
Here, I'm sharing a simple code for that, you'll understand easily.

```js
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

var goToTop = document.getElementById("goToTop");

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 30) {
    goToTop.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    goToTop.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body{
height:1500px;
width:100vw;
}
.goToTop{
    height:69px;
    width:69px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:white;
    position:fixed;
    right:30px;
    bottom:20px;
    z-index:1000;
    display:none;
}
.goToTop img{
    width:70px;
}
.goToTop.sticky{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div class="goToTop" id="goToTop">
      <a href="#body">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/collapse-arrow--v1.png"/>
      </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

OR
If I'm wrong
Or
You want me to fix your code only, then let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hello, yes, I would like to just edit my code. When I scroll down, then the arrow appears. When I tap on it it's changing to a black colour and transparent BG. When I scroll down again and the arrow appears again, it's still black without BG instead of returning to white with green BG how it was before the tap (this problem is only on the phone, on PC this problem doesn't occur).

Comment: any ideas? Thank you. @ShivamSharma